# Standard for X509 certificate sharing (java servlet)

Tags: java, servlets, cryptography, x509certificate

I'm trying to develop a simple web service using servlets and Apache Tomcat, in which a client and a server exchange their public keys; this to send some signed data in a further stage of communication.

I've read over the internet that the best way to share public keys is through X509 certificates to prove their reliability / integrity, is  that correct?

I have used Bouncy Castle and JCE to generate the keys and a self-signed X509 certificate, which has to be exchanged between the two parties. Here I got lost between different formats like PEM, DER and recommendations on sharing the bytes of the certificate (i.e. transferring the certificate's object via a `ByteArrayOutputStream` encapsulated in a `ObjectOutputStream`). Which is the correct way of doing this? How should I code it?

Side note: this software is intended for study purposes and not for real-world use, so it is okay to make big assumptions as "the connection is secure". This is why I preferred to keep it simple and not to implement SSL. However, if it proved to be really necessary I could try to use it.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**  this is how I solved the problem, thanks to @Lothar

```
X509Certificate taCert = Certificates.getCertificate();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JcaPEMWriter pw = new JcaPEMWriter(sw);
pw.writeObject(taCert);
pw.flush();
String pemData = sw.toString();
pw.close();
out.println(pemCert);
```

The function `getCertificate()` generates a X509Certificate using BouncyCastle and the resulting `pemData` is something like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

which is sent with a Content-Type `text/plain; charset=utf-8` through the `PrintWriter` provided by `response.getWriter()`. Client-side, the response is received through `HttpURLConnection urlConnection`, and read via `InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();`. More specifically,

```
InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

boolean hasInput = scanner.hasNext();
if (hasInput)
    return scanner.next();
else
    return null;
```

To create a `X509Certificate`, I use a `CertificateFactory`, considering `contactServerResult` as the string received from the server:

```
CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
certificate = (X509Certificate) fact.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(contactServerResult.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"))));
```

At the end I did not use a `PEMParser` when reconstructing the received certificate, because it returned a `X509CertificateHolder` rather than a `X509Certificate`, resulting in a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: There's nothing magical about certificates, if you aren't using any feature of them then there's no reason to use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format most if not all cryptography libraries support is DER. If you have an X.509-instance you simply call `getEncoded` and you have it. PEM is also widely supported but you need a parser (`PEMParser` in BouncyCastle for example) to create the certificates from it again.

I can't recommend serializing the objects using `DataOutputStream`. The object you serialize is dependent on the cryptographic provider that was involved when the certificate was created. If the other side doesn't have this provider available the deserialization will fail. If the other side isn't Java-based the data stream is completely useless, because it's java specific.

To answer your question, how to code it if we're talking about DER as format:

Sending the certificate (assuming within a servlet):

```
response.getOutputStream().write(certificate.getEncoded());
```

Creating a certificate from received data (using BouncyCastle as provider):

```
byte[] data = getDataFromSomewhere();
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
```

And for the fun of it, doing the same for PEM:

Sending:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JcaPEMWriter pw = new JcaPEMWriter(sw);
pw.writeObject(cert);
pw.flush();
String pemData = sw.toString();
```

Receiving:

```
String data = getDataFromSomewhere();
PEMParser pr = new PEMParser(new StringReader(data));
X509Certificate x509 = (X509Certificate) pr.readObject();
```

All examples are simplyfied, e.g. assuming that there is data to read and that the data actually represent a X.509 certificate. There are other things that can be DER- or PEM-encoded so you might get an exception while parsing or when doing the cast because the returned object isn't a certificate but for example a CSR.

Comment: You don't need Bouncycastle to read a PEM certificate, the `CertificateFactory` class can handle those too.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I tried to use the PEM representation of the certificate, but every time I receive it and read it, the PEMParser throws IOException: `java.io.IOException: -----END CERTIFICATE not found
 at org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader.loadObject(Unknown Source)
 at org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader.readPemObject(Unknown Source)
 at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser.readObject(Unknown Source)
 at com.example.giada.stickypolicies.model.Test.main(Test.java:24)` even if the certificate is well-formed (there is the correct `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` at the end).

Comment: @GiadaS You need to provide the code that produces the error and the text that it's parsing.

Comment: I added the code in the question, sorry it's a bit long, I thought a complete explanation was better

Comment: You don't need to send HTML. Just set the content type to `text/plain` and send the PEM data only without encapsulating it in `body`-tags. That way the other side can simply read in the data without the need of data extraction from HTML.

Comment: Thanks for yor advice! Changing the Content Type really helped. So I managed to make the `PEMParser` work all right, but then I got ClassCastException for `X509Certificate taCertificate = (X509Certificate) parser.readObject();` because the PEMParser returned a `X509CertificateHolder` instead of a `X509Certificate` (even if I sent a `X509Certificate`)... finally I managed to construct a certificate with a `CertificateFactory`, as I show in the updated question. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Is sharing certificates in pemData on request body vulnerable?

Comment: @GokulCjGrove Vulnerable to what? A certificate is public data so sharing it shouldn't be a problem independent of the format it's done.

Comment: I want to share certificate for verifying the identity of user. For example.. I am creating an access token binded with a certificate(OAuth 2.0 Mutual TLS) and I want to share the both access token and certificate to other servlet to verify whether the access token was generated by the user using the certificate. Thats Why I Asked whether it is vulnerable?